# how to read what I enter in address bar in php and getting data from it

Tags: php

I want to enter `mysite.com/#test1` in address bar . My site is configed so that index.php will load. And I want to read `mysite.com/#test1` in php so php could work with that string getting `test1` out of the address. Is that possible ?

This

```
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

gives me only

```
index.php
```

While in address bar I have `mysite.com/#test1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part after the hash is not sent to the server, so it is not possible to access it using PHP.

You could read it using Javascript and then submit it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Any string after a # in a URL is not sent to a server.

How about passing values like `mysite.com/index.php?variable=`

You can use a `$_GET` to get the value.

Answer (score -3):

print_r( $_SERVER );

and choose the best for you